# ToUnicodeEx is producing English instead of the right language

Tags: c, winapi, unicode

My goal is to write to a file a letter which is collected from the keyboard.
I am trying to figure out how to use the ToUnicodeEx function or something similar.
My code works only with the english language, when i convert the keyboard to another language, it still types in english letters.

What is wrong?

This is the relevant code:

```
dwThreadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId);
BYTE *kState = (BYTE*)malloc(256);
GetKeyboardState(kState);
hkl = GetKeyboardLayout(dwThreadId);
wchar_t UniChar[16] = {0};
//UINT virtualKey = MapVirtualKeyEx((UINT)character, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR, hkl);
UINT virtualKey = character;
ToUnicodeEx(character, virtualKey, (BYTE*)kState, UniChar, 16, NULL, hkl);
//printf("this is the char: %lc ",UniChar[0]);
//fwrite (UniChar , sizeof(wchar_t), wcslen(UniChar), file);
fputws(UniChar,file);
free(kState);
//fputc(character,file);
fclose(file); 
break;
```

Tried using

```
UINT virtualKey = MapVirtualKeyEx((UINT)character, 2, hkl);
```

instead; also didn't work.

Comment: You cannot use ToUnicodeEx() in a key logger.  The keyboard state and layout you'll get is for your own process, not the process that has the keyboard focus.  There is no way to get these properties for another process.

Comment: Then how come it works for english characters? And what solution do you propose?

Comment: I propose you stop trying to create a key logger.  Not what you want to hear but I suspect beneficial to 99.9% of all SO users.  Getting help with a program written for the right reason but useful for the wrong reason is pretty difficult at a respectful Q+A site like SO.  I trust you understand.

Comment: Why do you think this is a key logger, @Hans? The way I understand the question, he just wants to write input from the keyboard into a file. Erel, can you give us more details about what you're actually trying to do? You don't need to use all these functions just to get text input.

Comment: I've worked on several perfectly legitimate applications that captured keystrokes but were not key loggers.  Macro recorders and automated test utilities are two examples.  And even if he is writing a key logger, so what?  He's asking for technical advice, not moral judgement.

Comment: I used GetAsyncKeyState(character) and now im trying to input the character in the keyboard layout language into the file.

Comment: @ErelHansav "async" stands for asyncronous. There is no way to know if a key was pressed twice or held down between two sample values. Or what key was pressed after another key. So this function is not suitable for a key logger. (Maybe with the assumption of a slow typer and lots of CPU usage for fast cycling)